# Git delete file with a special characters in name

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to remove some files using git

```
rm $(git ls-files -o --exclude=standard)
```

The problem is file names contains symbols such as #, [], spaces and other, so I'm getting the "No such file or directory" error. How can I handle this?

Comment: Use `git clean` instead? Alternatively, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 (specifically the bit about `NUL` for how to do this safely and correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The `-z` option is useful here. It separates the files with a null byte rather than a space. If you have `xargs`, you could do something like this:

```
git ls-files -o --exclude=standard -z | xargs -0 rm
```

Alternatively, using a `for` loop in bash

```
git ls-files -o --exclude=standard -z | read -r -d $'\0' -a files
for i in "${files[@]}"; do rm "$i"; done
```

This reads the file names into an array, then loops through it, removing them one by one.